# Django: filter by Date and time

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I want to filter the queryset by date and time... I want to return all   queryset that grater than or equal todays dateTime

I try to do this and nothings happening

in viewset

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user. user_booking.filter(time_date__date__gt=now().date())
```

model class

```py
class BookingModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_booking')
    hall = models.ForeignKey(HallModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='hall_owner')

    time_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    booking_method = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `date.today()` here, or `timezone.now().date()`

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

request.user.user_booking.filter(time_date__date__gte=now().date())
```

This thus will list every object with a `date_time` field that has a date that is the same as the date when you call this function.

In case you do *not* want to filter on the logged in user, you should filter the `BookingModel` manager:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

BookingModel.objects.filter(time_date__date__gte=now().date())
```

> **Note**: the name of a Django model usually has *no* `Model` suffix, it is thus usually `Booking`, *not* <s>`BookingModel`</s>.

Comment: it give me empty list ... when i check db i found some date and time that grater than today

Comment: You used `now().date()`, and with `__gte` (not `__gt`)?

Comment: this is one example how i store dataTime "date_time": "2019-08-30T11:50:00.303983Z"

Comment: i used now().date() with __gte

Comment: @prg.dev: please share your models. At first sight, it looks like you might have stored it as a string somehow.

Comment: But then the query is `request.user.user_booking.filter(time_date__date__gte=now().date())`.

Comment: it stile give me empty list

Comment: @prg.dev: are you sure these dates are for the logged in user? Note that you make an extra filter with `request.user.user_booking.filter(..)`. Not only do you filter on `time_date`, but on the `user` as well.

Comment: no... I want to return all user booking **{time_date}** that grater than or equal todays time

Comment: @prg.dev: so of *all* users? Not of the logged in user?

Comment: @prg.dev: well then it looks like the user that logged in has no `BookingModel` objects with a `time_date` larger than (or equal to) today. Perhaps you should try for a different user.

Comment: i Have one more question if you don't mine ..... I want when i return the hall ... return  with it only bookings the grater than or equal to todays time

Comment: I use SerializerMethodField to return the booking and i want to return only the todays booking or grater

Comment: @prg.dev: the `hall` is just `item.hall` (with `item` an item of the queryset).

Answer (score 1):

It seems `self.request.user.date_created` is not queryset, but data field.

And according to your model code you have time_date field at BookingModel, but not at User one.

So, the queryset should look like this: `BookingModel.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).filter(time_date__gt=datetime.datetime.now())`

Comment: it give me empty list ... when i check db i found some date and time that grater than today

Comment: append your question with User class model code plz. It'll help to construct the right queryset

Comment: seems you have time_date field at BookingModel, but not in User one.
So, the queryset should look like this: `BookingModel.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).filter(time_date__gt=datetime.datetime.now())`

Comment: stile give me empty array